# Generate double entry table with different data

Tags: r

I am using R-exams and I want to generate a double entry table, but each time with a different set of values (I propose 5 different ones: data1,data2,data3,data4,data5), but it does not work, neither with a counter, nor with "sample".

How could I do it? Thanks

```
datos1 = c(0 , 2 , 4 , 2, 4 , 8, 13, 6, 12)
datos2 = c(11 , 2 , 4 , 2, 4 , 8, 3, 6, 12)
datos3 = c(12 , 2 , 14 , 2, 4 , 28, 3, 6, 12)
datos4 = c(13 , 2 , 4 , 2, 4 , 8, 3, 6, 12)
datos5 = c(1 , 2 , 4 , 22, 4 , 8, 3, 6, 12)

w9 <- sample(c(datos1, datos2, datos3, datos4, datos5),1)


tabla = cbind (expand.grid (list (Y = c ("3","5","6") ,
X = c ("6","8","9"))), count = w9)
ftable (xtabs(count ∼ Y + X, tabla ))
```

Comment: Hey Amelia, for a fixed value of `w9` what would you expect the output to be? As `count` is the same for each row in `tabla` the outputs for `xtabs` make sense to me.

Comment: If w9 is for example datos5, the output is  for rows 1 22 3, 2 4 6 and 4 8 12. I want that from a set of 5 possible vectors, randomly choose a group (either data1, data2 or....data5). I don't want to concretely put a group. When I set it to randomly choose one of the groups the output is a row matrix with all 1 or 2 or 3....., i.e. 1 1 1 1, 1 1 1 1, 1 1 1 1, which is not correct, according to the values of the vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification, Amelia :)

`c(datos1, datos2, datos3, datos4, datos5)` is combining them in to one long vector, and then sample is just taking 1 single value from these. Instead you want to put them in a list and then sample. This keeps them separate so sample is then looking over the list levels and taking one at random. See below:

```
w9 <- sample(list(datos1, datos2, datos3, datos4, datos5), 1)
# to extract it from the list back in to the same format as datos1, datos2 etc.
w9 <- unlist(w9)
```

**Edit:** Covariance

Following the **Example** section in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance). I'm assuming yours is the same style as this?

```
# package for data exploration 
# install.packages("data.table") # if not installed, run this line
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(tabla)
# X & Y stored as factors, converting to numbers
dt[, X := as.integer(as.character(X))]
dt[, Y := as.integer(as.character(Y))]
# weighted means of X and Y
dt[, mux := weighted.mean(X, count)]
dt[, muy := weighted.mean(Y, count)]
# need probabilities of each combo
dt[, p := count/sum(count)]
# covariance
cv <- dt[, sum(p*(X-mux)*(Y-muy))]
```

Comment: It comes out perfect. What I wanted. Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks Amelia! Please accept the answer when you have time, I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: Jonny, one more question. And how would you calculate the covariance in the obtained table?

Comment: Updated the answer for you :)

Comment: Jonny thank you very much. I am very grateful to you. Your answer has solved my problem.

Comment: No worries Amelia, hope you have a safe yet fun christmas :)